# Small integers caching in Python gives ambiguous results

Tags: python, caching, integer

I'm learning a bit of Python at the moment and I stumbled upon a weird thing i can't really explain:

As it says in Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256. When you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

and if I look at the [intobject.c](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/intobject.c) implementation I see the same range of values defined as `NSMALLNEGINTS`, `NSMALLPOSINTS`.

So when I test something obvious, like

```
a = 1
b = 1
print(id(a) == id(b)) # True
```

I get the same result everywhere.

However, when I move to bigger numbers (and when I say "bigger" I mean way over 256) I start getting different results which vary from IDE to IDE. For instance:

```
a=2**100
b=2**100

print(id(a) == id(b))

a = 1267650600228229401496703205376
b = 1267650600228229401496703205376

print(id(a) == id(b))
```

gives me `False`, `True` in VsCode test.py file and also if I use Visual Studio 2022, however it gives `False`, `False` in Jupiter Notebook file.

Or even something like:

```
a=259
b=259

print(id(a) == id(b))
```

Gives `True` in Visual Studio and a random online Python compiler, but gives false in Jupiter Notebook file.

Could someone please explain how actually integer caching works? I assume it's not entirely affected by Python runtime?

Update:
So I read a comment from Iain Shelvington and it looks like a compiler behavior regarding oneliners. But not entirely so. Look at the snippet below and you'll notice that for big numbers with operands in-between (e.g. 2**100) id comparison returns `False` regardless of where you run the code, and as for JupiterNotebook it indeed looks like since it executes line by line - it doesn't optimise integers if they are on different lines:

```
# The following code returns 
# (In VisualStudio 2022, VsCode (ver 1.77.3) and a few random online compilers):

#True
#True
#True
#False
#True
#===========
#True
#True
#True
#False
#True

# However in JupiterNotebook it returns:

#True
#True
#True
#False
#True
#===========
#True
#False
#False
#False
#False

a, b = 200, 200
print(id(a) == id(b))

a, b = 999, 999
print(id(a) == id(b))

a, b = 2**10, 2**10
print(id(a) == id(b))

a,b = 2**100, 2**100
print(id(a) == id(b))

a, b = 1267650600228229401496703205376,1267650600228229401496703205376  

print(id(a) == id(b))

print('===========')

a=200
b=200
print(id(a) == id(b))

a=999
b=999
print(id(a) == id(b))

a = 2**10
b = 2**10
print(id(a) == id(b))

a = 2**100
b = 2**100
print(id(a) == id(b))


a = 1267650600228229401496703205376
b = 1267650600228229401496703205376
print(id(a) == id(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really interesting, for what I could try myself I'd say:

0 and 1 (and maybe some others) are stored to fixed memory addresses so they get a fixed ID. Even compute against them keep the ID (0**100, 1**100)

The other numbers from a math operation get their own IDs like 2**100, 3**100, etc.

so It should be an easy/cheap way to handle 0 and 1 and/or small numbers

I did this exercise:

```
for i in range(0,300):
  a=2**i
  b=2**i
  print(f"{i} - True" if id(a) == id(b) else f"{i} - False")
```

with an interesting result:

```
0 - True
1 - True
2 - True
3 - True
4 - True
5 - True
6 - True
7 - True
8 - True
9 - False
10 - False
11 - False
12 - False
13 - False
14 - False
15 - False
16 - False
17 - False
the rest is false.....
```

I increased the base and the bigger the base the earlier it start to assign different IDs to variables. So someway it's related to the number size

So I don´t have an answer yet but I got fun trying to discover what's going on!